# Subtract datetime column and get result in seconds pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a df as:

```
Name    Date       Time
 A   02/20/2021   12:30:06
 A   02/20/2021   12:30:20
 A   02/21/2021   12:30:20
 A   02/22/2021   02:30:30
```

i am trying to combine them into one datetime and subtract current row with previous to get the difference columns of datetime in seconds like:

```
Name   Date        Time      diff
 A    02/20/2021   12:30:06   
 A    02/20/2021   12:30:20   14 seconds
 A    02/21/2021   12:30:20   86400 seconds
 A    02/22/2021   02:30:30   50410 seconds
```

I am trying this:

```
df['Datetime'] = df['Date'].astype(str)+' '+df['Time'].astype(str)


df[['diff']] = df.groupby('Name')[['Datetime', 'Result']].diff()
```

But it is giving me output as 0 days 00:00:10.I am not able to find proper solution anywhere.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create datetimes first by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then convert timedeltas by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str) +' '+df['Time'].astype(str))

df['diff'] = df.groupby('Name')['Datetime'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
  Name        Date      Time            Datetime     diff
0    A  02/20/2021  12:30:06 2021-02-20 12:30:06      NaN
1    A  02/20/2021  12:30:20 2021-02-20 12:30:20     14.0
2    A  02/21/2021  12:30:20 2021-02-21 12:30:20  86400.0
3    A  02/22/2021  02:30:30 2021-02-22 02:30:30  50410.0
```

For integers use [*integer na*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) for integers with missing values:

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('Name')['Datetime'].diff().dt.total_seconds().astype('Int64')
print (df)
  Name        Date      Time            Datetime   diff
0    A  02/20/2021  12:30:06 2021-02-20 12:30:06   <NA>
1    A  02/20/2021  12:30:20 2021-02-20 12:30:20     14
2    A  02/21/2021  12:30:20 2021-02-21 12:30:20  86400
3    A  02/22/2021  02:30:30 2021-02-22 02:30:30  50410
```

If need seconds instead `floats` add custom function with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str) +' '+df['Time'].astype(str))

f = lambda x: '' if pd.isna(x) else f'{int(x)} seconds'
df['diff'] = df.groupby('Name')['Datetime'].diff().dt.total_seconds().map(f)
print (df)
  Name        Date      Time            Datetime           diff
0    A  02/20/2021  12:30:06 2021-02-20 12:30:06               
1    A  02/20/2021  12:30:20 2021-02-20 12:30:20     14 seconds
2    A  02/21/2021  12:30:20 2021-02-21 12:30:20  86400 seconds
3    A  02/22/2021  02:30:30 2021-02-22 02:30:30  50410 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks it worked,,but when i am trying to convert diff column to int it is giving error as cannot convert non finite values to integer,,,i tried replacing NA also with blanks and again it gave error as invalid literal for int( ) with base 10: ' '

Comment: @naina - added to solution, need `.astype('Int64')`

Comment: i tried but now the error is cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64

Comment: @naina - Need upgrade pandas, `'Int64'` working `New in version 0.24.0.` - [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html)

Comment: I am unable to upgrade it..Any other way??

Comment: @naina - If check docs, then is not possible create `NAN` with integers in pandas versions before `0.24`.